# Openssl (OS X Yosemite) Installation Make Errors

Tags: c, openssl, osx-yosemite

While OpenSSL ver. 0.9.8za was already installed on my system (darwin64-x86_64-cc), I elected to install the latest version, 1.0.1j, using the instructions for UNIX systems, in the "INSTALL" file within the downloaded tarball.  I chose to configure with the 64-bit option, './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc', and then ran the makefile.  So far, so good.  After about a minute, as I was thinking the installation would be successful, the compiler displayed following error messages, after compilation terminated:

**Compile command line: './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc'** (Openssl suggestion for 64-bit)

```
duplicate symbol _OPENSSL_cleanse in:
../libcrypto.a(mem_clr.o)
../libcrypto.a(x86_64cpuid.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2 
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

The problem appears to originate in the linker, but then again, I'm still a command line novice.
So, given this error, what needs to be changed in order to fully compile OpenSSL 1.0.1j?
   When the automatic configuration route was taken (./config), the following error is given:

```
cc -I.. -I../.. -I../modes -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT
DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch i386 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -DL_ENDIAN  
DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m 
DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM 
DGHASH_ASM   -c -o obj_xref.o obj_xref.c
ar  r ../../libcrypto.a o_names.o obj_dat.o obj_lib.o obj_err.o obj_xref.o
ar: ../../libcrypto.a is a fat file (use libtool(1) or lipo(1) and ar(1) on it)
ar: ../../libcrypto.a: Inappropriate file type or format
make[2]: *** [lib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

Update: The "PROBLEMS" documentation suggests changing two lines in the apps/Makefile and test/Makefile:

```
"LIBCRYPTO= -L.. -lcrypto"
"LIBSSL=-L -lssl"
```

to:

```
"LIBCRYPTO=../libcrypto.a"
"LIBSSL=../libssl.a"
```

Re-attempting make afterward, the same message was given.

My sincere thanks for the help and comments by jww, Jonathan L. and others gave/made.  Should errors persist, I'll continue the search for the missing information and eventually post a solution.

Comment: Your problem is in the compiler command: `-arch i386`. We need to see how you configured, so please add the line in your problem description. Jonathan probably gave you the answer: use `Configure` to select the configure options. On OS X, you should also configure with `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` because ECDH is 2x to 4x faster. Other configure options should include `no-ssl2`, `no-ssl3`, and `no-comp` (they are all insecure). Also see [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: *... using the instructions for UNIX systems, in the "INSTALL"* - there's an `INSTALL.MacOS` you should be using (rather than `INSTALL`). But `INSTALL.MacOS` is pretty worthless, so you should probably use the OpenSSL wiki page [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation).

Comment: Hey, you, yes you: creep about to vote down anything on this page because you're unhappy with your life.  Just leave, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is.  Using XCode 6 (6.1.1, I believe) on Yosemite 10.10.1, I was able to get `openssl-1.0.1j` from [OpenSSL.org](http://www.openssl.org/) and extract it.  I then configured it with:

```
./Configure --prefix=/usr/openssl/openssl-1.0.1j darwin64-x86_64-cc zlib threads shared
```

With those, I was able to build, test and install without problem.  That's pretty close to what you did; I simply have noted the presence of zlib (compression) and requested thread and shared library support — and specified a slightly out-of-the-way location to install it.  (The top-level directory specified with `--prefix` existed but was empty.)  I tried adding `sctp` to the configuration options, but no dice — an SCTP header is missing, so I didn't bother to try further.

Comment: `zlib` is used for compression, and compression is insecure (it leaks information). You should probably configure with `no-comp` (in addition to `no-ssl2` and `no-ssl3`).

Comment: @jww: thanks for the information.  I can see why `no-ssl2` and `no-ssl3` would be a good idea.  I'm curious about why `no-comp` (and presumably dropping `zlib`) are necessary — or how compression leaks information when non-compressed does not.  Can you point me to relevant URLs or search terms?  (Oh, and I've just seen your comment to the main question; if that's got the information I need, then you don't need to respond!)

Comment: Check out [BREACH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH_%28security_exploit%29) and [CRIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CRIME). BREACH exploited compression in higher level protocols (like HTTP), while CRIME exploited it in lower level protocols (like SSL/TLS). I don't recall the disposition in SPDY, which requires compression.

Comment: @jww: thanks.  I tried Google with 'openssl compression information leak' and it was pointing to those.  It's helpful to have confirmation that those are what you had in mind.  I must have been asleep.